# Are the newspapers allowed to print the house number when it's subject to a Closure Order?

Tags: united-kingdom, privacy, right-of-publicity, freedom-of-press

If a house is subject to a Closure Order made under the [Anti-social Behaviour, Crime and Policing Act 2014](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2014/12/part/4/chapter/3/crossheading/closure-orders?timeline=false), can the press, especially local newspapers, publish the house number as well as the street name?

On a related note, what recourse would the tenant have if they were to be harassed due to this publication?

Comment: I think you would be wise to consult a local attorney.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, unless the Magistrates' Court makes an Order restricting such publication.
2. Harassment is an offence, so one option is to [report it to the police](https://www.police.uk/advice/advice-and-information/sh/stalking-harassment/how-to-report-stalking-harassment/). Or, alternatively one could make contact with a [support group](https://www.police.uk/advice/advice-and-information/sh/stalking-harassment/support-victims-harassment/)